# Achievement list in Android app doesn't show fully

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

The Android app shows a reduced list of achievements:

> [image: android]

In web, I see the full history:

> [image: web]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1626721325f7f)

Comment: Did you try to refresh the list?

Comment: @ShadowWizard off course! This is the first what I did.

Comment: Huh, knew is sounded familiar.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure about dup. In my case today votes contain more rep changes than showed in the app.

Comment: I'm 99.999% sure that it is the same issue. Something "crops" the achievements mid-way, in that case it was just of that day.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so why not to close old question as dup of mine? :)

Comment: Well, it's the same report... no answers here, or better explanation. :) (not worse of course, just not better enough to justify such action.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard my post contains comparision with web version. You can see a diff to futher investigation. E.g. appering a bagde could be a source of a bug. :)