# Achievement history is mysteriously missing on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Up until today, my achievements on mobile were showing from 30 days ago to today. Now it only shows from yesterday to today as seen below:

[image: Blank entries in achievements]

As you can see, it only shows *part* of yesterday, no 7 days ago or 30 days ago. The rest of the entries are blank. Another example:

[image: Blank entries in achievements]

Is this a bug? The history was working fine yesterday.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2 (also tried updating to 1.6.2.5)
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288323/339911) for Android app.

Comment: @alexolut Sadly there's no solution :(

Comment: I know. It's for developers mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.6.5.4.

The problem was that the app only showed about 50 distinct reputation events, not 50 rolled up events, and those 200 points for hats was actually 40 upvote events.  Now it matches the top bar.